# How to Define Foreign Key Relationships in Entity Framework other than the default method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a problem I am trying to solve with the Entity Framework 6.0  and hope someone here can give some direction on. I am much more comfortable with ADO.NET but want to do this project in EF.

I have an object called **Policy** and another called **PayPlan**

```
public class Policy
{
    //Various properties not relevant

    public PayPlan PaymentPlan { get; set; }
}

public class PayPlan
{
     public int PayPlanId { get; set;}

     public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, in this example, a **PayPlan** is a child object for a **Policy**. It may be null, or there may be a single instance of a PayPlan associated with a policy.

When I run the model builder, it creates the tables and inserts a Foreign Key into the Policy Table for the record in the PayPlan. This doesnt really work for me though because 1) I would like to keep the Db schema similar to a previous version of the application wherein the PolicyId is a ForeignKey into the PayPlan and 2) With Cascading Deletes, if the PayPlan were to be deleted it would take the Policy with it and I need this to be the other way around. The Policy is the root object form which all other objects in the Db draw their relations. PayPlan, btw, is just a single example for this discussion but in the actual project the Policy object would contain a number of child objects associated with it in a similar manner.

My question, how do I set this up, either through Data Annotations or via the Fluent API, to achieve the schema I described?

Comment: If you want PayPlan to have FK to Policy, shouldn't then there be `PayPlan.Policy` property, and not `Policy.PaymentPlan`? With current model, one PayPlan can be associated with multiple Policies, which is not compatible with what you want in database. Side note - if you have existing database, it might be easier to generate your model from it, and not try to replicate it with code-first.

Comment: That would, to me, imply that the Policy was subservient to the PayPlan and not the other way around.  After all, in that example, a PayPlan could have a null Policy which would be an impossibility as a PayPlan would only exist as defined by the Policy, but it would be perfectly acceptable for a Policy to not have a Payplan..

Comment: I hear you on the Db. The existing Db is about 8 years old and the product of 11 different people working on it over that time applying various band-aids. I want to clean up the database. But you may still have a point, in that I could write/define the new Db first then build the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after digging a little bit about this on EF 6 after you mentioned you are using that version and found this:

Apparently alternate keys are not supported on EF 6. As @rowanmiller on this Github issue:

> Unfortunately this is a limitation of EF6. You can not have a foreign
>   key property in a one-to-one relationship, unless it is also the
>   primary key property. This is essentially because EF6 doesn't support
>   alternate keys/unique indexes, so you can't enforce that a non-primary
>   key property is unique. The fact that you can do it when the foreign
>   key property isn't in the entity is a bit of a quirk... but obviously
>   not something we would remove :smile:.
>
> BTW alternate keys (and therefore this scenario) is supported in EF
>   Core.

[Mapping foreign key in HasOptional().WithOptionalDependent() relation](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/159#issuecomment-274889438)

You can still have the FK as you want, but you can't have the FK property on your `PayPlan` class. If you do, you'll ended up with two FKs. So, if you configure your relationship like this:

```
public class Policy
{
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public PayPlan PaymentPlan { get; set; }
}

public class PayPlan
{
    public int PayPlanId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Policy Policy { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PayPlan>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.Policy)
        .WithOptionalDependent(p => p.PaymentPlan)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

You will end with this on SQL:

[image]

Didn't know about this since I never had this scenario. Sucks a lot. BUT you still can do it using EF core :), which is cool.

**EF Core answer just for the record**

You can solve this also using the FluentAPI. (I prefer the FluentApi rather than polluting my models with Attributes). Also, since you didn't mention which version of EF you are using, I assumed you are using EF Core.

```
public class Policy
{
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public PayPlan PaymentPlan { get; set; }
}

public class PayPlan
{
    public int PayPlanId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Policy Policy { get; set; }
    public int? PolicyId { get; set; }
}
```

Context class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Policy>()
        .HasOne(a => a.PaymentPlan)
        .WithOne(b => b.Policy)
        .IsRequired(false)
        .HasForeignKey<PayPlan>(b => b.PolicyId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

This will produce the following tables on SQL:

[image]

Comment: I am on EF 6. I went ahead and added that to the original description. I will try this suggestion out in just a moment.

Comment: Note that I updated to make the relationship optional. Forgot about that.

Comment: @Goblyn27 check my updated answer.. I`m afraid it's not good news =/.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of afraid that would be the case. Thank you for all the effort and research you put into it though.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your requirements correctly, you want to build model like this:

```
public class Policy {
    [Key]
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }
    // this attribute is not required, but I prefer to be specific
    // this attribute means navigation property PaymentPlan
    // is "anoter end" of navigation property PayPlan.Policy
    [InverseProperty("Policy")]
    public virtual PayPlan PaymentPlan { get; set; }
}

public class PayPlan {
    [Key]
    public int PayPlanId { get; set; }
    // define foreign key explicitly here
    [ForeignKey("Policy")]
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Policy Policy { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Update: the above works in EF Core, but does not work in EF 6. EF 6 treats this as one to many relationship (and is correct in that, because one Policy could have multiple PayPlans). To create one to (zero or) one relationship, you can create model like this:

```
public class Policy
{
    [Key]
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }                
    [InverseProperty("Policy")]
    public virtual PayPlan PaymentPlan { get; set; }
}

public class PayPlan
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Policy")]
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }        

    public Policy Policy { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So PayPlan doesn't have its own Id and instead has PolicyId which is both PK and FK. That way, only one (or none) pay plan may exist for one policy.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that just now. The error message was a mind-f**k. "PayPlan_Policy_Source: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'PayPlan_Policy-Source' in relationship 'PayPlan_Policy'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key Properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'"

Comment: Yes you are right. I tested this model with EF Core, in which that works as you expect, but in EF 6 it indeed throws error you posted.