# entity framework 1-0..1 relationship with inherited base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some classes which are inherited from a base class and in a 1-0..1 relations, here is the Base Class:

```
public class Base
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And my inherited classes are:

```
public class Resim : Base
{
    public string Resim_Orjinal_Ad { get; set; }
    public string Ad_Guid { get; set; }
    public string SEOAlt { get; set; }
    public byte Tip { get; set; }
    public byte Konum { get; set; }

    public virtual Varyasyon Varyasyon { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Varyasyon : Base
{
    public string VaryasyonAdi { get; set; }
    public string VaryasyonOzellik { get; set; }
    public string VaryasyonDeger { get; set; }

    public virtual Resim Resim { get; set; }
}
```

In context I want to build a relation like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Varyasyon>().HasOptional(x => x.Resim).WithRequired(y => y.Varyasyon);
```

When I use add-migration command in package manager console an error occures:

```
 Varyasyon_Resim_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Varyasyon_Resim_Target' in relationship 'Varyasyon_Resim'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.
```

Identity ID Key is in Base class, there fore when I use an annotation like
    [Key, ForeignKey("Varyasyon")] in inherited classes, databese structure get destroyed.

I found a solution like this:

```
  public class Resim : Base
{
    ...
    public int BaglantiID { get; set; }       
    public virtual ICollection<Varyasyon> Varyasyon { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Varyasyon : Base
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Resim> Resim { get; set; }
}
```

In context:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Varyasyon>().HasMany(x => x.Resim).WithRequired(y => y.Varyasyon).HasForeignKey(y => y.BaglantiID);
```

But this solution is not 1-0..1 relation, how can I solve this problem in 1-0..1 relation?

Comment: you want a fk Varyasyon on Resim? Maybe this can help you:https://stackoverflow.com/a/47749197/2689390

Comment: Thank you @jpgrassi it is helpfull :)